# Neo4J user profile data modeling

Tags: neo4j, modeling

I need to design a data model, which stores user profile information. User node may contain name, address, telephone as attributes. Amount of users is expected to be increased dramatically. 
At the same time, I want to store each users' skills and hobbies which are entered by the users themselves during the profile creation.
One user can enter multiple skills and hobbies. Of course multiple users may share a certain hobby or a skill.

We also have a requirement to filter users by skill or hobby. That is, if the hobby (Badminton) is given, we need to find all the users who like Badminton.

1. Would it make sense to create hobbies, skills as nodes? My understanding is, this will increase the query performance but, amount of distinct hobbies, skills users happen to enter may increase the number of nodes in the database.
2. Would it be good to store skills and hobbies as attributes of user nodes? My understanding is, search by an attribute over all the user base would decrease the query performance.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your phrasing of the question.

- Skills and hobbies are shared amongst users
- Find all users who like Badminton

This clearly indicates that skills/hobbies are entities, or nodes. There's no need to prematurely optimise, and the number of nodes will increase but steady at some level (the number of skills and hobbies is not infinite). Also, the performance of queries is unrelated to the total size of the graph, so it may not really matter that the size of the graph has grown- the performance will depend on the size of the subgraph touched. Unless you're looking at 10s or 100s of billions of nodes, it is pretty safe to add skills and hobbies as nodes, and not worry about performance at this stage.